# Android scaling image vertically

Tags: android

I am trying to create a mini progress bar that will indicate how much data a user has used. It doesn't even need to animate, I just need it to change in size based on a variable I have set up. So when I load up the screen, how much of the progress bar is filled up will depend on a variable I have set up in Java.

I have managed to get this working horizontally by using

```
scale =  new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f);
```

This will start the image from nothing and stretching out to its full size, so I can use it as a horizontal progress bar which is great.

Now I woulda thought doing this vertically instead would be a simple matter of just changing the fromY to 0 and the toY to the new size I want. However when I do this, by changing the fromY to 0.0f and the toY to 2.0f, the image actually moves and stretches at the same time rather than stretching. Also the image moves position for some reason. It starts off higher up than where I positioned in using XML, and moves down to the original position and stretches out to the new scale I set up.

The code I use to try and stretch it vertically is

```
scale =  new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

So can someone please explain why it stretches horizontally fine, but when I try to stretch it vertically, it suddenly moves and stretchs at the same time.

Would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: It sounds like you are scaling the image from a reference point that is outside the image. I believe you want to use the center. The last two values in the method call should be the x/y coordinates of the point about which the object is being scaled. So make sure these are the center of the bar

Comment: But why is this not an issue with horizontal scaling? With horizontal scaling I just leave them at 1.0f for the last two, and the image stays in the same place.

Comment: Figured it out actually. You were right about the last two, I started messing around with them, as they didnt seem to do anything. Ended up changing the last one to 50.0f and now it works perfectly, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate you have solved the animation issue you mentioned, but based on you saying you don't even need the bar to animate, the `ClipDrawable` class may make your life simpler. You can define one in an xml layout and then set the clip level from your code, which will clip the given drawable by the given amount.

Check this out for more details on how to use it:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip

Hope that's of some help.

Comment: Actually that will be perfect for the next function I have to create, cheers